# Как передать на страницу заказа ид записи в таблице с корзинами пользователей?

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток всем!
Есть две таблицы в БД: корзина и заказы. Структуры этих двух таблиц представлены ниже.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на странице "Оформить заказ" в БД в таблицу с заказами уходил код корзины со всей информацией.
Нужна помощь именно с кодом.

Благодарю всех, кто  откликнется :)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а какой код у вас выполняется при нажатии кнопки "Оформить заказ" ?

Comment: INSERT INTO `orders` (`Код корзины`, `Фамилия клиента`, `Имя клиента`, `Отчество клиента`, `Адрес почты`, `Телефон клиента`, `Адрес доставки`, `Примечания`, `Способ доставки`) 
VALUES ('', 'Иванов', 'Иван', 'Иванович', 'ivanov@gmail.com', '+375(32) 321-31-32', '5345345345245', '', 'Самовывоз')

И вот тут вопрос как раз возникает в том, как код корзины добавлять

Comment: обратитет внимание что в запросе вставляется пустой код корзины VALUES ('', 'Иванов', 'Иван', 'Иванович', 'ivanov@gmail.com', '+375(32) 321-31-32', '5345345345245', '', 'Самовывоз'), видимо по этому он не пишется в базу, точнее пишется пустая строка

Comment: Да, я это вижу. Здесь какая ситуация: поля Код корзины связаны в таблице заказы и корзина. И, при оформлении заказа, в БД как-то нужно заносить ещё и код корзины пользователя, который делает заказ. В этом, собственно, и состоит вопрос.

Comment: По идее код корзины должен с клиента передаваться или он должен храниться в сессии клиента на сервере и браться оттуда. Во многих движках данные о текущем состоянии клиента и его персональных данных хранятся либо в куках на клиенте, либо в php сессии на сервере.

Comment: Да скорее всего он в сессии или приходит из скрытого поля в корзине

Comment: Проблема состоит в том, что он никак не хочет брать код корзины :(